# Is my ExpirableLazyObject not thread safe? Is there a race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

A while back, I created a Java class that encapsulates lazy initialization into a `LazyObect`. It maintains concurrency and threadsafety and also provides a `reset()` method to clear the value.

```
public final class LazyObject<T> {

    private volatile T value;
    private volatile boolean updated;
    private final Supplier<T> supplier;

    private LazyObject(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }
    public T get() {
        if (!updated) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (!updated) {
                    value = supplier.get();
                    updated = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    public void reset() {
        if (updated) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (updated) {
                    updated = false;
                    value = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static <B> LazyObject<B> forSupplier(Supplier<B> supplier) {
        return new LazyObject<B>(supplier);
    }
}
```

I wanted to try and take this concept a little farther. If the `LazyObject` is holding a very large object that is used only for a short time (like a memory-intensive hashmap), I want the value to be destroyed after a period of no use. If it ends up being used again later, then it will initialize again and reschedule another destruction cycle.

So I created `ExpirableLazyObject`.

```
public final class ExpirableLazyObject<T> {

    private final LazyObject<T> value; 
    private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    private final long expirationDelay;
    private final TimeUnit timeUnit;
    private volatile ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledRemoval;

    public ExpirableLazyObject(Supplier<T> supplier, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor, long expirationDelay, TimeUnit timeUnit) { 
        value = LazyObject.forSupplier(() -> supplier.get());
        this.expirationDelay = expirationDelay;
        this.executor = executor;
        this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
    }

    public T get() { 
        if (scheduledRemoval != null) {
                scheduledRemoval.cancel(true);
        }

        T returnVal = value.get();
        scheduledRemoval = executor.schedule(() -> value.reset(), expirationDelay, timeUnit);

        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

It takes a `Supplier` and some needed arguments to schedule the destruction of the value. It will delay the destruction every time `get()` is called. Of course, I could do designs that force the client to handle the creation and destruction of the value via GC, but I like APIs that manage the instances internally.

The benefits are I can persist cached objects long enough to support an operation, and I can lazily and regularly refresh parameters automatically.

However I cannot shake the feeling the `get()` method might have a race condition, but I cannot figure out an exact reason why. I don't know if I need some synchronized blocks or if I am not properly identifying atomicity. But every synchronized block I made to appease my concerns would greatly undermine concurrency or introduce a new race condition. The only way I can see to prevent any race condition (if there is one) is to synchronize the entire method. But that would undermine concurrency. Is there really a problem here?

***UPDATE***
It has been established there is a race condition. I think I have a few ideas on how to fix this, but I'd like to hear any suggestions that would efficiently accomplish this and maximize concurrency.

Comment: I know this probably isn't the answer you want to hear, but have you looked at the `SoftReference` class?

Comment: No, I like pre-built libraries. I'll take a look to see if this solves what I need. But even if it does, I would be curious to read answers to the original post.

Comment: I would imagine the main race would be that you lose the reference to the future (i.e. two threads call `get()`, both `schedule()`, but only the last future is saved, so it will not be possible to cancel that, and `reset()` is called when the scheduled time period expires..) - so, is this a potential race you are after?

Comment: It's your choice obviously, but where `SoftReference` can be useful is that the removal strategy also takes into account how much empty heap is left, not just a fixed timer.

Comment: Yeah I'm researching it right now, and that is a compelling case as long as it has the functionality I need (or it can be created around it). I may be posting questions on it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a race condition.

T1:

```
    //cancel original future
    if (scheduledRemoval != null) {
            scheduledRemoval.cancel(true);
    }
```

T2:

```
    //cancel original future AGAIN 
    if (scheduledRemoval != null) {
            scheduledRemoval.cancel(true);
    }
```

T1:

```
//set new future (NF)
scheduledRemoval = executor.schedule(() -> value.reset(), expirationDelay, timeUnit);
```

T2:

```
//set even newer future (ENF)
scheduledRemoval = executor.schedule(() -> value.reset(), expirationDelay, timeUnit);
```

In the last step you overwrite `scheduledRemoval` with a new value without cancelling that future. Any subsequent calls will only see `ENF`, while `NF` will be inaccessible and uncancellable (but still active).

The easiest solution is via `AtomicReference`:

```
private AtomicReference<ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduledRemoval;

public T get() { 
    ScheduledFuture<?> next = executor.schedule(() -> value.reset(), expirationDelay, timeUnit);
    ScheduledFuture<?> current = scheduledRemoval.getAndSet( next );
    if (current != null) {
            current.cancel(true);
    }

    T returnVal = value.get();

    return returnVal;
}
```

Note that you can still run into a situation where by the time you'd want to call `current.cancel()`, it already fired. Avoiding that would require some more complicated signalling, which I'm not sure is worth it.

Comment: I knew it. My gut feel told me something to that effect. Based on this information, I guess I'd have to synchronize the whole `get()` method. Am I right? I cannot think of another way to resolve this unless... I do a check inside the task itself. Maybe I can pass the task some flags or something before it proceeds to cancel...